# Launch PhpStorm with the command line using zsh

Tags: phpstorm, command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm looking to launch PhpStorm via the command line using zsh + oh-my-zsh.

```
pstorm .
```

I have read up on the topic and have seen countless suggestions pointing to "Create command-line launcher" and have messed with it extensively. I have also messed with the `Application Settings > Shell Path` by setting it to `/bin/zsh`, `usr/bin/zsh`, etc.

I always end up with:

```
zsh: command not found: pstorm
```

One thing I have noticed is when setting the Shell Path to `/bin/zsh` specifically, the text is greyed out in the field, as if to indicate it's invalid?

I have been regularly restarting iTerm to enable any new changes that may have been made to .zshrc.

Anyone out there done this successfully? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The `Tools` menu of PhpStorm contains a command named `Create command-line launcher`. It asks you where to create the launcher (full path + file name) and on Unix-like systems it defaults to `/usr/local/bin/pstorm`.

Also, on Unix-like systems, `/usr/local/bin` usually is on the path. You can run `echo $PATH` in the terminal to find out if this is the case or not. If it's not there you can easily add it by adding the line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your `.zshrc`.

You can also use a different path for the command line launcher (in the `bin` subdirectory of your home directory, for example, or in other directory that already is in `$PATH`).

---

`Shell path` under the `Tools -> Terminal` page of the program settings is a different thing (and it doesn't help you launch PhpStorm from the shell; it is the other way around). It contains the path of the shell to launch (by PhpStorm) in its Terminal window (menu -> `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Terminal`).

Answer (score 6):

Latest standalone version doesn't come with pstorm shell script. We can create one at `/usr/local/bin/pstorm`.

```
#!/bin/sh

open -na "PhpStorm.app" --args "$@"
```

Give permission to execute `pstorm`.

```
chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/pstorm
```

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone

If you are using Toolbox App, it can generate scripts for you.

1. Open the Toolbox App and click The screw nut icon in the top right
   corner.
2. In the Toolbox App Settings, enable Generate shell scripts.
3. If necessary, change the shell scripts location.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone

Answer (score 0):

If you use Toolbox for installing PhpStorm then you can do next:

1. Enable shell script generation in PhpStorm Settings:
   `Toolbox->PhpStorm Settings->Shell Scripts->Enable->Generate scripts locations`
2. Put path in `Shell script location` (for example): */usr/local/bin* (you can find your path via command `echo $PATH` in terminal
3. Go back and edit your alias for launching PhpStorm to whatever you like (by default it is `phpstorm`)

TL;DR: If you have troubles - go to official blog docs:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/08/23/toolbox-app-1-11-whats-new/

Comment: It seems on linux these settings aren't there.